# C++ windows executable compiled with Linux needs additional DLL

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, mingw-w64

I want to write C++ code and compile it for Windows from an Linux machine.
I began with something simple:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a, b;

int main()
{
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a+b;
}
```

I compiled it using : i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o suma.exe.
When I run it from the windows machine, it says : 
**The code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++-6.dll was not found.Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.**
When I downloaded this DLL, it gave me an error for other missing DLL.
How can I compile code without any DLL error?